# How do I reject a character in bash?

Tags: string, bash, replace, character

I'll give two examples:

Example 1,

```
# create files "a" to "z"     
touch {a..z} 
ls
a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v x w y z
```

but I want to reject `n`

```
a b c d e f g h i j k l m "" o p q r s t u v x w y z
```

Example 2, (what I really want to do)

```
ls
c1 c-2 ca4 cA5 cs1 cs2 cs3 cs4 cs5
rm c* #but not starting with "cs"
```

With example 1, I want something like:

```
rm c*(!s) #this command will give an error, but I want to remove all strings starting with "c", not "cs"
```

How do I reject a character?

Comment: You may be interested by the _pattern matching_ section on the bash manual, and also the `extglob` shell option. Try `man bash`.

Comment: @RenaudPacalet thx! I really value these comments because it helps understand Linux

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You seem to be asking for a solution in the area of pattern matching, so a negated character class fits the request pretty well:

```sh
rm c[^s]*
```

The `[^s]` matches exactly one character other than `s` (including uppercase `S`), so the overall pattern will match

`c1`, `c2`, `ca`, `clover`, `c12`, `cS`, `c@:,.`, *etc*,

but not

`c`, `cs`, `cs1`, `cs101`, or `csience`.

You can find more details in [the Bash manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Pattern-Matching).

Comment: The string `c` of course starts with `c` so maybe `rm -f c c[^s]*`. The tag is `bash`, but maybe worth noting that the POSIX syntax is `[!s]` (exclamation mark instead of caret), which also works in bash. `[^s]` won't work in certain `sh` implementations.

Comment: This will work provided you just want to "reject" files with "s" as the second character in the name. If you want to avoid files with an "s" anywhere in the name, it's much more difficult (`*[!s]*` will *not* do this -- it will match files that have at least one non-"s" character in the name).

Comment: I discovered this yesterday by accident, but it gets more difficult the more you try. With `touch` command I wasn't able to reject patterns between {a..z}. I don't know how to do it yet, but I'll mark this as the right answer anyway.

Comment: @SatoshiNakamoto `{}` expansions ("brace expansions") are significantly different from glob (wildcard) patterns, and you can't use the same tricks with both of them. If you want to generate lowercase letters other than "s" with a brace expansion, you can use `{{a..r},{t..z}}`.